# Proportional-resonant controller for output voltage ripple compensation in a buck converter

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, control-system, converter, pid-controller

If we are to compensate the output voltage of a buck converter using a proportional-resonant controller, what should be the approach to estimate the K<sub>p</sub> and K<sub>i</sub> values of the controller?

Comment: Why not simulate the unavailable circuit and find out for yourself?

Comment: Yes Andy, Working on it at the moment. Was just curious whether anyone in the community has tried this approach before 